# Getting write timed out SdkClientException while uploading a directory with large file size

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-s3-client

I am uploading a file directory from windows system to S3 bucket using S3TransferManager uploadDirectory method below is the code for that ..

```
     private static void copyFromServerToS3(S3TransferManager transferManager, File sourceFile, String s3URI)
         throws URISyntaxException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {

     DirectoryUpload directoryUpload;
     String prefix = S3URLUtils.key(s3URI);
     if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(prefix)) {
         directoryUpload = transferManager.uploadDirectory(UploadDirectoryRequest.builder()
                 .source(sourceFile.toPath()).bucket(URLUtils.bucketNameForURI(s3URI)).s3Prefix(prefix).build());
     } else {
         directoryUpload = transferManager.uploadDirectory(UploadDirectoryRequest.builder()
                 .source(sourceFile.toPath()).bucket(S3URLUtils.bucketNameForURI(s3URI)).build());
     }
     CompletedDirectoryUpload completedDirectoryUpload = directoryUpload.completionFuture().get();
     completedDirectoryUpload.failedTransfers()
             .forEach(fail -> LOG.warn(String.format("Object [%s] failed to transfer", fail.toString())));
 }
```

For the above code when I am trying to upload a directory to s3 from windows file system which is having multiple files then the above code uploads the files which are small in size but its not uploading one of the file which is around 530 mb size and it fails with below exception ...\

```
 exception=software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Write timed out)] failed to transfer
```

Is there something I can do to get this bigger file too uploaded to S3 bucket ? Please suggest.